# Solve Makefile dependencies

Tags: c, dependencies, header-files, circular-dependency

**How to solve this dependencies?**

In my project every file includes header file with the same name.

Header files includes another header files (dependencies).

And after all i have this dependencies:

```
parser.h -> lexer.h -> str.h 
parser.h -> tables.h -> bst.h -> str.h
```

So when i'm not include *str.h* in *bst.h*, i have 'unknown type name' error.

When i'm include *str.h* i have 'type redefinition' error.

As i understand, this can be solved by right dependencies in Makefile.

Before this i was have simplest *Makefile* (list of objects, one command).

**Also, whats is the simplest way to solve circular dependencies?**

```
instructions.h -> bst.h
bst.h -> instructions.h
```

So i need datatype of data for instructions prototypes, but also need an pointer to instruction in bst.h for goto instructions.

I'm writing in C99, tried lot's of dependency variations in Makefile, but no result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a Makefile issue, you just need *include guards* in your header files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on Oli's comment, in str.h:

```
#ifndef __STR_H__
#define __STR_H__

/* str.h contents here */

#endif
```

Comment: And make sure to use different names (`__BST_H__` etc.) in different files.

Comment: @creichen and Oli: Thank you a lot! It's very useful method. Made changes in all files of project, everything works good.